# How to get list of Plotly chart points after decimation?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I use https://plot.ly/javascript/ for displaying some data. I receive more than 1000 points from the back-end. As I understand there is a decimation algorithm, which reduces the number of chart-points to draw. Is it possible to access the list of points after decimation? If yes, how can I do it?

Link to the original question https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-get-list-of-chart-points-after-decimation/4949

Thank you, in advance.